# bind text to a style in word

Tags: c#, office-interop

I want to bind a style for each paragraph in word.
The program fills mergefields with data from a dataset.
The mergefields come from a predefined template with styles.

Per row/paragraph I have to bind a conditional Style to the paragraph,
so this is the code I use:

```
    objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add(ref objTemp, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
    objDoc.CopyStylesFromTemplate(objTemp.ToString());  //copy the styles to the active document

    objWord.Selection.set_Style(objDoc.Styles[stijl]);
    objWord.Selection.TypeText(resultaat);
```

When I open the document, the paragraphs have the right font etc.
However, they are bound to the style "Normal" in the document.
The tab space is also off in each paragraph.

But, the paragraph which has no text (only spaces) is bound to the predefined style in the output document.

Is it possible to bind the layout to the paragraphs?
If so, this would also solve my tab spaces problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apperently, if you switch the last 2 lines of code, the problem is fixed.

So, here's the anwser:

```
    objWord.Selection.TypeText(resultaat);
    objWord.Selection.set_Style(objDoc.Styles[stijl]);
```